# C# sync tool - FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc compare - Windows 10 changed time stamp by switch from winter to summer time

Tags: c#, file, synchronization, backup, windows-10-desktop

I wrote a tool to backup and sync my folders. (Tool written in Visual Studio 2022 with .NET Framework 4.8)
To copy the files I use System.IO.File.Copy(sourcePath, targetPath)
To compare the files I use System.IO.FileInfo.LastWriteTimeUtc
I create my backup on a USB stick.
After the automatic summer time changeover (+1 hour), all time stamps in Windows file system have changed (added 1 hour to LastWriteTime and LastWriteTimeUtc).
Now, my tool wants to update all files. This is currently not a problem, but it will be a problem with the clock reset to winter time in October. Then files in the target are more up-to-date than in the source.

Why is the date stamp changing? Is that normal?
Do I have to check the time zone when comparing?
But I thought the UTC timestamp is there to not do that...

Here a picture from one FileInfo (This phenomenon occurs with several thousand files):
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rrfA1.png)